# Can we use the sequences of 3 launch images in iphone/ipad

Tags: ios

Can we use the sequences of 3 launch images in iphone/ipad?

Comment: Quite simply, no.  What happens is, you immediately **cut to the identical image**, while you do your start up or whatever.  99% of apps do this. There's the "actual iOS launch image" and then in your first scene, when you first launch the app, cut to an identical image.  Then add your animations, forms, or whatever the case may be.  That;'s how it's done in 99% of apps.

Answer (score 2):

No. A launch image is just one image (for that particular device/scale/orientation).

We show an animation in one of our apps, which starts immediately **after** launch (on the root view controller).

Comment: Exactly.  This is what happens in basically every app.  It's just one of those freaky things they don't put in a manual, but every app does! Heh.

Answer (score 0):

Technically not. But you can show additional images yourself after the app finished loading. The Default.png is used to display something (instead of a black screen) while your app loads.

Once it finished loading, it is immediately replaced with your main window's content. Then you can add UIImageViews or UIViewControllers to display anything you would like. But at this point your app is done loading and it would be a waste of time to show anything else, than your app's live content.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use sequence of images in default launch.

But you can do with the customise the code on view to change the images sequentially with a timing difference once the default image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

No. you can use only one image of different type of device like normal size,3.5 inch and 4 inch

You can add a new viewcontroller which will display the different type of splash screen image  in the application didFinishLoading.

This way you display the more splash screen display a bit longer.